# Android Wear Yes or No Confirmation dialog?

Tags: wear-os

How to add an android notification which asks for a Yes or No confirmation on an android wear?

[image: Yes or NO Confirmation]

Answer (score 2):

To build this into a notification, you would need to create a custom notification.  See here for creating custom layouts for notifications - https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#CustomNotifications

There is no predefined Wear activity/layout for this type of yes/no confirmation.  You would need to build this yourself - perhaps with a BoxInsetLayout and two ImageButtons for yes and no.

You can find info on the BoxInsetLayout here - https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html#same-layout

This will ensure that your layout looks ok on both square and round devices.

If you're looking for a common Wear experience, you'll probably want to use a DelayedConfirmationTimer and a ConfirmationActivity.  These are commonly used to give the user time to cancel their input and to provide an indication that a process is complete, respectively.  You can find details here https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html

Comment: This answer isn't related to question. I guess there is only one way to show default styled confirmation dialog - build layout yourself and use it in activity or fragment.